# Python: Send multiple POST requests on the same page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, http-post

Is it possible to send multiple HTTP POST requests to a server using selenium webdriver?

If, for example the user IDs are auto-incremented and the first 1000 followers had followed me, would it be possible to run something like the following on a site where POST requests dont return a reload:

** The website obviously requires the user to be signed in to do such actions hence the selenium approach.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://example.com/myfollowers")

for userid in range(1, 1001):
    driver.post("http://example.com/unfollow/{}".format(userid))

driver.close()
```

Below is a snippet example of the Post request made to a site.

```
General:
Request URL:http://example.com/unfollow/1
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.168.1.1:80
Response Headers

Request headers:
Accept:*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Cookie:ob-i=1; 
Host:example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/user/followings
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.26.02 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why shouldn't it work?

"where POST requests don't return a reload" Please explain what you mean by this!

Anyway, [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) seems to be more suitable for this task:

Here is a simple example:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://example.com/myfollowers")
print("myfollowers returned: " + r.content)

for userid in range(1, 1001):
    r = requests.post("http://example.com/unfollow/{}".format(userid))
    print("unfollow returned: " + r.content)
```

Comment: By not returning a reload I mean that it doesn't submit a form and return a page refresh/new page (the program can continue running in the same tab without waiting on a server response).

Comment: Then this will still work. `r.content` in the last line will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

don't know how to make it using selenium web driver. but you can send multiple post request using AJAX. Its quite simple language you can learn it within 2 days if you know little bit javascript. you can learn it from w3schools Try it.